# Calculating the most probable radius for an electron of a hydrogen atom

Tags: probability, hydrogen

For the $\rm 1s$ state, the wavefunction is of the form: $\displaystyle{ Ne^{\Large{{-\frac{r}{a_0}}}}}$.

So from [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydr.html) link and from what my professor said, the probability function will be $N^2e^{-2\Large{\frac{r}{a_0}}} \cdot r^2 \sin \theta$. Then radially, we get the most probable value to be $a_0$. If we do the same for the angle $\theta$, we get that the most probable value for $\theta$ will be $\displaystyle{\frac\pi2}$. What is the significance of this? We certainly don't expect any unsymmetrical distribution in $\theta$ and $\phi$ since the wavefunction is radially symmetric.

EDIT:

Additional question:

If I convert $\psi$ back in rectangular cartesian coordinates, I get $\displaystyle{\psi = Nexp\left(- \frac {\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{a_0}\right)}$. The probability function will be only $|\psi|^2$ in this system. Then in this case, we don't get any peaks radially. How do we explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability distribution in the 1s state is indeed uniform in solid angle (i.e. the electron has the same probability of being found in any ray from the nucleus). The result comes out as $\pi/2$ because you are measuring the probability that the electron lies in a band of latitude between $\theta$ and $\theta+d\theta$, and such a band has most area when at the equator (i.e. when $\theta = \pi/2$).

---

I think you need to understand exactly what you are asking when you ask:

> What is the most probable value of $\theta$?

It means this: integrate the probability density $|\psi|^2$ over a region with $\theta<\theta'<\theta+\delta\theta$ and the whole range of $r$ and $\phi$, for some fixed $\delta \theta >0$. Find the value of $\theta$ which maximizes this integral, $\theta^\ast$ say, and then take $\lim_{\delta \theta \to 0} \theta^\ast$. As the probability density is independent of $\theta$, the value of the integral is proportional to the area of the sphere you are integrating over, which is maximized when $\theta^\ast = \pi/2$ (as I said, its a band around the equator).

For the same question with $r$, the integration region is a thin spherical shell at radius $r$, whose volume is proportional to $r^2$. Thus, although the value of $|\psi|^2$ is strictly decreasing as a function of $r$, the value of the integral at first increases (because the volume of the shell increases $\propto r^2$), and thus shows a maximum at non-zero $r^\ast$.

Comment: So if I convert $\psi$ back in rectangular cartesian coordinates, I get $\psi = Ne^{- \frac {\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{a_0}} $. The probability function will be only $|\psi|^2$ in this system. Then in this case, we don't get any peaks radially. How do we explain that?

Comment: The probability function on the sphere is uniform in whatever coordinate system you choose. The reason $\theta=\pi/2$ is maximum is because this value of $\theta$ corresponds to the largest area on the sphere. There's no violation of rotational symmetry.

Comment: So you're saying that we get the same result in rectangular cartesian. Could you show the process?

Comment: I'm not sure 'showing the process' would be useful as I think your problem is conceptual... $|\psi|^2$ is a probability *per unit volume*. When you change from cartesian to spherical polar coordinates the $\sin \theta$ term comes from the volume element in these coordinates ($dV=r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta d\phi$) and does not imply anything about where the electron is more likely to be found.

Comment: I know that $|\psi|^2$ is the probability _density_. When you say that the volume element does not imply anything about the probability, shouldn't it be the same when we calculate it for $1s$? What I've been trying to ask is that if maximising $|\psi|^2 r^2 sin \theta $ wrt r is justified, why isn't it so for $\theta$?

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer... hopefully it will help!

Comment: Perhaps it might be illuminating to simply *compute* $\langle r \rangle$ , a sensible multiple of $a_0$, versus $\langle \theta\rangle=0$.